# How can I write the nested linq query

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

How can I write the below SQL query in linq?

`select * from Employee where Email = (select User_Email from tbl_Login where User_Email='abc@demo.com' and User_Password = 'demo123')`

What I have done is:

`from tblemp in ctx.Employees where tblemp.Email = (from tblLogin in ctx.tbl_Login where (tblLogin.User_Email == login.User_Email && tblLogin.User_Password == login.User_Password))`

However, it is throwing an error.

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In method syntax:

```
var employee = ctx.Employee
  .Where(e => e.Email == ctx.tbl_Login
     .Single(l => l.User_Email = "abc@demo.com" and l.User_Password = "demo123")
     .User_Email)
```

This returns an `IEnumerable`. If you are expecting a single result use `Single` instead of `Where`. You can also use `First` to take the first result from that set.

Comment: Awesome! Can you mark the response as the correct answer?